# Website pages are not opening correctly on nginx

Tags: nginx

I am trying to setup a Question2Answer website (yoalfaaz.com) on nginx with Ubuntu. Now, the homepage of the website does load but any other page doesn't load correctly. Mostly, when I click for any post on my website, it opens the homepage again and sometimes just breaks the layout.

Here's the `sites-available file`

```
server {
        listen 80 ;
        listen [::]:80 ;

        root /var/www/yoalfaaz.com/html;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name yoalfaaz.com www.yoalfaaz.com;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
        }

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #

        location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
        }
}
```

Now, previously only the homepage was opening and for every other page, I was getting 404 Not Found error. So I made some changes to `try_files` line and after that, the website pages are not opening in the correct way.

I have also checked for any kind of errors, but there are none and if I try `nginx -t` then it also shows successful. Please help me out, guys.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the problem is not nginx, but your application.

Looking at the HTML of your pages I see this:

```
<link href="./qa-plugin/q2a-embed-master/qa-embed.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./qa-plugin/q2a-tag-list-widget-master/tag-list.css?" TYPE="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./qa-plugin/Welcome-Widget-master/welcome-widget.css?" TYPE="text/css">
```

The URLs of your CSS files are relative to the **current path**, so basically the location changes if the URL contains something that resembles a path or subdirectory.

Take for example this URL: `http://yoalfaaz.com/4966/pardesi-ke-naam`

Trying to load the CSS file `./qa-plugin/q2a-embed-master/qa-embed.css` on that page will load `http://yoalfaaz.com/4966/qa-plugin/q2a-embed-master/qa-embed.css` which results in a 404 error.

You should change your code to output absolute URLs or *root-relative* URLs.

Example:

- Absolute URL: `http://yoalfaaz.com/qa-plugin/q2a-embed-master/qa-embed.css` or `//yoalfaaz.com/qa-plugin/q2a-embed-master/qa-embed.css` (the last one is *protocol-relative* URL)
- Root-relative URL: `/qa-plugin/q2a-embed-master/qa-embed.css` (always will start at the root of the domain)

Comment: Hello, thanks for your time and I tried Root-relative URL method but it didn't work. I still think that there is some nginx config problem because on my previous hosting (hostgator) this website was working fine and I haven't changed anything in the website files on this new hosting.

Comment: I've accessed your website again and I don't see you're using root-relative URLs for the CSS files. Can you actually try changing it until you get those root-relative URLs in the HTML source code?